# UDP echo on specific interface

Tags: linux, networking

I have a virtual interface called TAP1. Packets come in on TAP1 from a thing I'm testing. I would like to set something up to take any UDP packet that comes into TAP1, swap the source and destination IPs and ports, and send it back into TAP1. So if a packet with a source of 10.10.10.10:5000 and a destination of 1.2.3.4:100 arrives on TAP1, I would like this program to send a packet with a source of 1.2.3.4:100 and a destination of 10.10.10.10:5000 on TAP1, with the same payload. I know how to do this with a python script using scapy, but I need something higher performance (> 100Mb/s).

I've tried something called xinetd, which supports the UDP echo protocol. That does what I want: it sends whatever payload it received back to the sender. But it has some problems:

- The UDP echo protocol uses port 7, and I need it to work for any port
- It seems to expect to have only one IP address, and I need it to work for any destination IP address
- I can't get it to work. I tried binding it to the address 1.2.3.10 and running `ifconfig TAP1 1.2.3.10`, but that doesn't work. I can connect to it with socat, and it echoes the payload I send it, but it connects over loopback instead of TAP1, no matter what settings I pass to socat. And socat is the only thing I can get to work with it: anytime I try to send packets with something like scapy, they just get ignored, even when I use the same source IP and port that socat is using.

I think this approach might be higher-level than I really need. What I want is the virtual equivalent of a box with a singe ethernet port. Any UDP packets you send it on that ethernet port come back out with their source and destination IP addresses swapped, and their source and destination ports swapped. Is this a thing that exists?

Comment: You can only bind to an address that actually exists on one of your ports. You would have to use raw sockets to spoof other addresses.

Comment: You can configure `xinetd` to run an echo server on any port, port 7 is just the default. But I don't know of any way to make a server that responds to *every* port. This would have to be done using something like BPF.

Comment: Code the server in C. However, at greater than 100MB/s, that's 800Mb/s which means you are looking at a 2.5Gb/s interface as a 1Gb interface may not be able to handle it. You may also have to code threading in the server to handle any parallel transfers.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant 100Mb/s. Thanks for the help, I'll try writing a c server that uses a raw socket.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some C code to do this. It seems to be able to do somewhere around 800Mb/s on an old Xeon, which I think is pretty good. In the end though I'm going to use Trex which does what I actually wanted (testing NAT) much better. Here's my C code, if this is useful for anyone:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h> /* the L2 protocols */
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>      
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>

// Used for debugging
void printbytes(char *bytes, int numbytes);


// Porgram that takes a UDP packet received on the given interface, swaps the source and destination IP addresses and the source and destination ports, 
// and sends it back out the same interface
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Takes one argument: the name of the interface to bind to
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <interface>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    char *interface = argv[1];

    int saddr_size , data_size, daddr_size, bytes_sent;
    struct sockaddr_ll saddr, daddr;
    unsigned char *buffer=malloc(65535);
    // Create a raw socket with UDP protocol
    int sock_raw = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW,  htons(ETH_P_ALL));    // For receiving
    if (sock_raw < 0) {
        perror("socket\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int sock = socket(PF_PACKET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_RAW);            //For sending
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("socket\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
    saddr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    saddr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
    saddr.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex(interface);

    if (bind(sock_raw, (struct sockaddr*) &saddr, sizeof(saddr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed\n");
        close(sock_raw);
        return 1;
    }


    memset(&daddr,   0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
    daddr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    daddr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
    daddr.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex(interface);
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &daddr, sizeof(daddr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed\n");
        close(sock_raw);
        close(sock);
        return 1;
    }

    struct ifreq ifr;
    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "%s", interface);
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, (void *)&ifr, sizeof(ifr)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "bind to %s failed\n", interface);
        // close(sock_raw);
        // close(sock);
        // return 1;
    }

    // Get the mac for this interface as a string (from /sys/class/net/<interface>/address)
    char* filepath;
    if(asprintf(&filepath, "/sys/class/net/%s/address", interface) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to make filepath");
        return 1;
    }
    char mac_str[18];
    FILE *fp = fopen(filepath, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s\n", filepath);
        return 1;
    }
    fgets(mac_str, 18, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    free(filepath);
    // printf("%s\n", mac_str);
    // Convert the MAC string to a byte array
    unsigned char mac[6];
    sscanf(mac_str, "%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx", &mac[0], &mac[1], &mac[2], &mac[3], &mac[4], &mac[5]);


    while(1)
    {
        saddr_size = sizeof (struct sockaddr);
        daddr_size = sizeof (struct sockaddr);
        //Receive a packet
        data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 ,(struct sockaddr *) &saddr , (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);

        if(data_size <0 )
        {
            printf("Recvfrom error, failed to get packets\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else {
        // printf("Received %d bytes\n",data_size);
        // printbytes(buffer, 20);

        struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) buffer;

        // Check to see if the source MAC is the MAC we set. This stops us from infinitely copying and recopying the same packet
        if (memcmp(eh->ether_shost, mac, 6) == 0) {
            // printf("Our packet, skipping\n");
            continue;
        }

        // Copy source MAC to destination MAC
        memcpy(eh->ether_dhost, eh->ether_shost, 6);
        
        // Set source MAC to our mac
        memcpy(eh->ether_shost, mac, 6);

        // Swap source and destination IP addresses and UDP ports
        struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)(buffer + sizeof(struct ether_header));
        uint32_t temp = iph->saddr;
        iph->saddr = iph->daddr;
        iph->daddr = temp;
        struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr *)(buffer + sizeof(struct ether_header) + sizeof(struct iphdr));
        uint16_t temp2 = udph->source;
        udph->source = udph->dest;
        udph->dest = temp2;

        // printbytes(buffer, 20);

        //Send the same packet out
        bytes_sent=write(sock,buffer,data_size);
        // printf("Sent %d bytes\n",bytes_sent);
        if (bytes_sent < 0) {
            perror("sendto");
            exit(1);
        }
        // sleep(1);

        }
    }
    close(sock_raw);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}

void printbytes(char *bytes, int numbytes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbytes; i++) {
        printf("%#04x ", (unsigned char) bytes[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");   
}
```